# Does Clear Data on App Settings clears all Android KeyStore stored for that certain app?

Tags: android, database, keystore, android-keystore

Just want to know if Clear Data in App's Setting **clears all Android Keystore stored** in that certain app? Or it leaves certain bits of data?

Android Keystore I'm referring to is similar to this KeyStore. See Tutorials below.

[From Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#UsingAndroidKeyStore) 
[From Medium Tutorial](https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b) 
[From Android Authority Tutorial](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/)

Comment: Thank you Amit Vaghela for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> clears all Android Keystore stored in that certain app? Or it leaves
>   certain bits of data?

Yes, It will reset all data of that application.

**Clearing the data**, however, will remove any user data, databases, etc -- this includes things like account settings, persistent preferences, etc.

Clearing the data should revert the application back to it's state as it was when you first installed it.

As an example, assume we have a Twitter application. 
Clearing the data would remove any information at all, including your login information, who you're following, whether or not you want to be notified of new tweets, and things like that.

In short, **it delete all applications data.**

Check [description for more details](https://www.androidpit.com/clear-app-cache-vs-clear-app-data-difference)

Comment: I was trying to find a reference that says clearing data clears keystone entries for that app as well but I couldn't find anything on this. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Clear Data in App's Setting will clear only the data, created / generated run-time by user. Like, preferences, database etc.

It will not clear data, stored at the time of app building

Comment: So that would mean if I store data in Keystore it won't be reset? so there would be bits of unused data after uninstallation.

Comment: I would like to know, how we can store data in Keystore.?? because I dont know...or which Keystore are you talking about...

Comment: For security, we can store data in Keystore. Only the app can access data saved in keystore. I'll put the tutorials in my question for more info. But these tutorials don't say if it will be erased after user decides to Clear Data. Just want to know if it also resets it or it leaves data residues.

Comment: Thanks buddy to sharing me such a unpredictable knowledge. And I am pretty sure that your keystore will be removed on Clear Data.

Comment: Thank you  Amit Vaghela and Dhruv Patel for the answer. Yes **Clear Data option in Settings does resets the data stored in keystore.**